# Import of files in one folder from another folder

Tags: python

I know there are similar questions asked but what I found is not very clear to me in this simple setting. Given this directory tree how can I import a function from `file1.py` into `file2` (we call the interpreter from the `file2.py`)? I would like this setting to work independently on where `main_folder` is, that is if I copy `main_folder` to a different directory, the imports would still work well.

```
main_folder
    folder1
        file1.py (with a function func())
    folder2
        file2.py
```

Comment: What/where is the start script with which the Python interpreter is called initially?

Comment: The starting script is the file2.py

Comment: The answer involving `SourceFileLoader` should give you what you want, but in the long term you should really learn how to make and use packages.

Comment: What would be then a solution using packages?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`SourceFileLoader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.machinery.SourceFileLoader) from [`importlib.machinery`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.machinery) to import from a path.

So you can use:

```py
# file2.py

from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader

PATH = "../folder1/file1.py"
file1 = SourceFileLoader("module.name", PATH).load_module()
```

Or if you would `import` from a package then you can use:

```py
# file2.py

from folder1.file1 import func
```

If you would like to use the package approach then you will need to run it from `main_folder`.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add absolute path to [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path).

> **`sys.path`**
>
> A list of strings that specifies the search path for modules. Initialized from the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, plus an installation-dependent default.
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list, `path[0]`, is the directory containing the script that was used to invoke the Python interpreter. If the script directory is not available (e.g. if the interpreter is invoked interactively or if the script is read from standard input), `path[0]` is the empty string, which directs Python to search modules in the current directory first. Notice that the script directory is inserted before the entries inserted as a result of `PYTHONPATH`.
>
> A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes. Only strings and bytes should be added to `sys.path`; all other data types are ignored during import.

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(sys.path[0]).resolve().parent / "folder1"))
import file1
```